# Set Error Marker in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, user-interface, web, extjs

I want to have some field to clear out if I enter something into another field. If that field that a value it should a error marker. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the Field Component level you have access to a function called markInvalid(string msg).  You can use this into mark the field.
[markInvalid API Doc](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/Field.html#method-Ext.form.Field-markInvalid)